# CSRF cookie not set. Django auth

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-authentication, django-csrf

Here is my "login" function that I am using to authenticate users when they provide their credentials in NextJs website fronend:

```
export const login = (username, email, password) => async dispatch => {

    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    console.log(csrftoken);

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    };

    const config_two = {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        }
    };

    console.log(config_two)

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
    const body_two = JSON.stringify({ username, password });

    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/auth/jwt/create/`, body, config);
        const res_two = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/`, body_two, config_two);
        
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });

        dispatch(load_user());
        toast.success("You are logged in");
    } catch (err) {
        toast.error("Something went wrong");
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL
        })
    }
};
```

For one purpose I had to include another post request to get tokens from the database which are provided by rest_framework.authtoken.models when users are registered. However, when I try to run this function I receive the following error attached here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9YNf.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWSb2.png).

It says that the csrf cookie is not provided, but I add it in the header in config_two constant that is sent with the request.

Looking forward to hearing possible solutions indicating on my mistakes. In advance, thank you for your time.

I read the documentation several times, watched videos in YouTube, but it didn't help. I am expecting it to accept my request and send me a token as a responce.